# C# regrouping some elements into different groups by their friendship without cycles

Tags: c#, algorithm, dictionary, graph, grouping

I am working on solving a problem of grouping some elements into different groups by their friendship.

For example,

Input:

```
 R1: R2, R6, R8, R10   // all elements in one group are friends
 R6: R1, R7, R8, R12 
 R8: R2, R5, R6, R10 
 R4: R11, R15, R16, R13  // **UPDATE** this is a group that do not have overlap with all other groups
```

For R1, all R1's friends' friends are also R1's friends who need to be classified into  the same group and so on.

Expected output:

```
 R1: R2, R6, R8, R10 , R7, R5, R12
 R4: R11, R15, R16, R13   // **UPDATE**
```

The output may be two or more groups.It depends on the input.

Now, the data is stored in a dictionary>  of C# in Visual Studio 2012.

I find that there may be cycles in the grouping process.

Example, R1 ---> R6 ---> R8 --> R6

Would you please help me find how to solve the cycle problems.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: A bit of demo code would be great. Also, please provide the desired result for your example case. If you just want to eliminate duplicates, look into [HashSet<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb359438(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Show us an example input, an expected output, and the output that you actually have.

Comment: @Grant Winney, DasKrümelmonster , Dialecticus, I have updated the post.Thanks !

Comment: @Original Poster : For R1, all R1's friends' friends are also R1's friends who need to be classified into the same group.

Then even R12 should be friends with R1 ?

Comment: @cvraman, because R12 is a friend of R6, R12 is also in the group of R1.

Comment: @user3356689 : I added an edit so that R12 was added to the expected output.

Comment: @cvraman, my input is a special case of all elements can be put in one group finally. But, in general cases, this is NOT true. What if we are given 100 groups, the final result may be only 5 groups ? Thanks !

Comment: @user3356689 : Can you give me an example for the general case, where you have multiple groups as output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo Code Shown Below :

```
    private static Dictionary<string, List<string>> ProcessData(Dictionary<string, List<string>> data)
    {
        var processedData = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
        var masterList = new List<string>();
        foreach (var value in data.Keys)
        {
            if (!masterList.Contains(value))
            {
                var friendList = FindFriends(data, value);
                masterList.AddRange(friendList);
                processedData.Add(value, friendList);
            }
        }
        return processedData;
    }

    private static List<string> FindFriends(Dictionary<string, List<string>> data,string source)
    {
        var friendMasterList = new List<string>();
        var friendQueue = new Queue<string>();
        if (data.ContainsKey(source))
        { 
            foreach (var value in data[source])
            {
                friendQueue.Enqueue(value);
            }
            while (friendQueue.Count > 0)
            {
                var value = friendQueue.Dequeue();
                if (!friendMasterList.Contains(value))
                    friendMasterList.Add(value);

                if (data.ContainsKey(value))
                {
                    foreach (var value2 in data[value])
                    {
                        if (!friendMasterList.Contains(value2))
                            friendQueue.Enqueue(value2);
                    }
                }
            } 
        }
        if (friendMasterList.Contains(source))
            friendMasterList.Remove(source);
        return friendMasterList;
    }
```